# Can a single ASPState database be used for multiple websites

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, asp.net

Is it possible for two or more website to share a single ASPState database? If security or performance were big concerns then I'd probably use separate databases. But is there any reason why two websites couldn't share a database?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a huge security risk.  Each application will have (read/write!) access to each other's state info.  It's up to you whether or not you want to go there (obviously not recommended) but you're better off using different databases.